# How to export as web (.gif) whithout getting error in photoshop cc 2015. (2gb ram) (1gb graphics)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, gif, cc-2015, error

[image]

This error comes when I click on save button..(In Windows 10)

Comment: 673 Frames @ 800x600? What else did you try? Probably not enough RAM, 2GB is absolute minimum, 8GB are recommended. Did you try a smaller animation?

Comment: Decreasing the resolution of animation (50p) makes exporting happen..but I want to export my animations in original resolution....Can anyone please help me...plz

Answer (score 2):

The animation seems too big for your machine. Some options would be:

1. Get more RAM
2. Export on a different computer (with more RAM)
3. Render as video or PNG sequence and convert it to GIF with a different tool with better memory management than Photoshop.

Comment: I like the 3rd one....but rending any video takes up to 30mins...when I click on render video option photoshop freezes and takes to much time to pop up render video dialog box...any helpz. About it.